# How to return value from a popup (Mopups) in .NET MAUI

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

Much like you can get the selected value from the following

```
string response = await Shell.Current.DisplayActionSheet("Do you really want to delete this card?", "Cancel", null, "OK");
```

,how do I use Mopups to return a value from the popup after it is dismissed? I want to create custom dialogs.

I am currently injecting the IPopupNavigation service and showing the popup using the following code if it is relevant

`await popupService.PushAsync(confirmationPopup);`

Answer (score 4):

I share a solution with [TaskCompletionSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1?view=net-7.0).

Here is how I define my custom Mopup code behind page. Suppose there is a button and when we click the popup will be closed. There is also a ReturnValue property. We can return this value when we close the popup.

```
public partial class MyPopupPage
{

    TaskCompletionSource<string> _taskCompletionSource;
    public Task<string> PopupDismissedTask =>  taskCompletionSource.Task;

    public string ReturnValue { get; set; }
    public MyPopupPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReturnValue = "Hello World";
        MopupService.Instance.PopAsync();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        _taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
    }

    protected override async void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();
        _taskCompletionSource.SetResult(ReturnValue);
    }
}
```

This how I show the popup and get the ReturnValue:

```
//create a new popup instance
var popup = new MyPopupPage();

 //show the popup
await MopupService.Instance.PushAsync(popup);

// the program will block this line until SetResult method invoke in popup OnDisappearing method
var rvalue =await popup.PopupDismissedTask;
```

For convenience I just set the ReturnValue as type string and you could use any other type as you want, for example you could also set `TaskCompletionSource<int> _taskCompletionSource`.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create an entity to store the data.

```
 public class PopupResult
    {
        public string ReturnData { get; set; }
    }
```

Second, you can create a method in the popup page to return the data to the MainPage.

```
 public partial class MyPopup : Popup<PopupResult>
    {
        private PopupResult _result;
        public MyPopup(PopupResult result)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _result = result;
            myLabel.Text = _result.ReturnData;
        }

        void Button_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            _result.ReturnData = "Return data from popup";
            Dismiss(_result);
        }
    }
```

Last, You can get the data form the popup page.

```
 var result = await Navigation.ShowPopupAsync(new MyPopup(popupResult));
    
 await DisplayAlert("Result", $"Result: {result.ReturnData}", "OK");
```